# Entity Framework 5 return SQL stored procedure single result efficiency vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, entity-framework, stored-procedures

If I have access to a stored procedure named procResults, which just returns a row of data, does picking out a few single elements instead of the entire row cause multiple queries to the DB?  For example, if I have:

```
Dim MyEntity As WhateverEntities = New WhateverEntities 
Dim ResultName as String = MyEntity.procResults.Single().FullName
Dim ResultEmail as String = MyEntity.procResults.Single().Email
```

Does this result in two actual queries to the DB, or does the initial query store the entire row in memory and just serve me the two columns I am asking for?  Ideally I would just like to return those two columns instead of the entire row but don't know what the most efficient way to do that would be.

Comment: imho the only part where EF caches results is when you use [Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj573936.aspx). `Note that DbSet [...] always create queries against the database and will always involve a round trip to the database even if the entities returned already exist in the context`. Find: `The Find method [...] uses the primary key value to attempt to find an entity tracked by the context. If the entity is not found in the context then a query will be sent to the database to find the entity there.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot answer from `VB.Net` side, but what you could do is:

You can use SQL Server Profiler to trace what happens in database when you execute your code. You'll see how many times your Stored Procedure has been executed.

This is a MSDN article, explaining how to use this tool: [How To: Use SQL Profiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650699.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim MyEntity As WhateverEntities = New WhateverEntities 
Dim ResultName as String 
Dim ResultEmail as String 

With MyEntity.procResults.Single()
        ResultName = .FullName
        ResultEmail = .Email
End With
```